# Are there any industry standards for referring to specific aspects of a web page?

Tags: website-design

Some specific examples I can think of :

- Should you say "carousel" or "slider"?
- "main navigation" or "top navigation"?
- "background image" or "background skin"?

"Header" and "Footer" are the only ones I can think of having any kind of standard due to semantic html.  Most other page features seem to have multiple ways to refer to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any standards or "official" names, but what you can do is to use a UI glossary. Try for example:

- http://ui-patterns.com/patterns
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb226821(v=vs.85).aspx

Also consider this thread: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/what-are-some-good-user-interface-words-phrases